# Read PHP output from array with AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

My PHP is outputting data like this:

```
$data['full_feed'] = $sxml;
$data['other_stuff']= $new;
echo json_encode($data);
```

So, in my jQuery, I'm doing this.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'untitled.php',
    type: 'GET',
success: function(data) {
    console.log(data['full_feed']);
});
```

This comes back undefined. So does `console.log(data.full_feed)`. I'm getting back from PHP a valid JSON object, but missing how I can "parse" it correctly.

Comment: you didn't tell jquery that you're expecting json back, so `data` is going to be a plain string. either use `.getJSON()` instead, or include `dataType: 'json'`

Comment: @MarcB Wow. Not sure how I missed that one. That did the trick. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Parse "data" parameter in response with jQuery.parseJSON function. Then use parsed.full_feed value. Like below:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'untitled.php',
    type: 'GET',
success: function(data) {
    data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
    console.log(data.full_feed);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like @tilz0R said or for your example to work you need to tell the browser you are sending a json response. So need to set content type header like

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($data);
```

to see what the server is returning do console.log(typeof data). If its a string you need to parse it. if its an object, it is already parsed.

Also you can put dataType:'json' in your ajax call to let jquery know you are excepting a json response.